# Convert Excel text string of hours minutes and seconds to time format

Tags: excel

I have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet that has times in text format that I need to convert to time so I can do averages etc upon them. 
For example in cell A1 it can give a variation of results eg
123 hours 15 minutes 04 seconds
Or
12 hours 49 minutes 10 seconds
All the way down to
00 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds

At the moment my head is frazzled and can't think of a way of converting this text to time automatically so we don't have to re type every time as the text string is an output report from a database so the format of that cannot be changed.
Any help is gratefully accepted!

Comment: can you provide some sample data

Comment: So if I understand correctly all the values that you need to convert contain the texts hours, minutes and seconds? Even though it may be doable using Excel functions it seems to me a better way is to write your own vba function and call that function to transform the data. Not sure if you want to write something in vba though or that you are looking for a pure Excel solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- `MID( text, start_position, number_of_characters )` to retrieve the hours/minutes/seconds
- `FIND( substring, string, [start_position] )` to search for "hours/minutes/seconds" to know from what position to retrieve the data
- `=VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(A1)))` to convert the string into number

I see that the input looks like HHH hours MM minutes SS seconds so it should be easy.

This would be the example for the hours:

```
=VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN((MID(A1,(FIND("hours",A1)-4),3)))))
```

Input: 123 hours 45 minutes 40 seconds Output: 123

Comment: Bear in mind that, internally, Excel stores dates as whole numbers (counting from Jan 1, 1900) and times as proportions of a day. You can extend the answer given by @Alexander by using the `TIME` function to convert your three values (hours, minutes and seconds) to Excel's internal format for the purposes of calculating averages, differences, etc. Excel's formatting can, of course, be used to display its internal values in an appropriate format.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm having trouble putting the mid, find and value together. What if the cell in mind with the text string was A1, what would be the actual formula you would use? Sorry to be a pain but I just can't think straight today. Must be the pollen!

Comment: `=VALUE( TRIM( CLEAN( MID( text,(FIND( "hours", A1 ) - 4), 3 ) ) ) )`

@NeilHall it would look something like this. First you find the "hours" substring, the actual number is in front of the substring so you substract 4 (1 for space 3 for number of hours) from the return of the `FIND`. Then with `MID` you take the number as a string and convert it.

Comment: @alexandrucimpanu when I used the exact wording from the above formula the result is just #Name? I know I must be going wrong somewhere

Comment: @NeilHall the exact formula is in the answer, if you do not get the correct result I sugest you decompose it to see what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that helped me with something similar, it involved brackets but was surprisingly easy.

I was trying to copy and paste YouTube transcripts where up to 23 minutes it's fine

23:59

But it gets funky after 24:00:00

It let me choose a custom number format where it matched what I had previously

So I put that into the output format in quotes
=TEXT(A1234,"h:mm")

and it finally gave me what I wanted

24:01 etc.

I couldn't figure out how to have the numbers turn into... Excel's format?